# Android "universal" webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm developing an hybrid app for android, but android webview rendering varies a lot depending on os version. So android 2.3 webview renders and behaves differently from android 4.0 webview which renders and behaves differently from android 4.4 webview...all this fragmentation is a real mess and makes it a problem to develop an html based app. I'm not talking about different screen sizes or densities, i'm talking about specific webview bugs or rendering engines.

Does exists an "universal" webview component (opensource or commercial) that i can embed in my app so that i don't have to write specific webview css hacks just to get the same rendering and behaviour on any android > 2.3 version?

I know there are some experimental projects such as https://github.com/davisford/android-chromium but couldn't find any production-ready project.

Comment: No solution found...chromeview seems to be the best candidate, but only when 2.3 devices will become an insignificant percentage in the android universe

Comment: @GiorgioAndretti Have you found solution for this?

Comment: No, honestly there is no such component. Now, question is outdated so current "specific" behaviours are less frequent with modern android versions, but if you really need to support old versions, there is no solution

Answer (score 4):

This is what you are looking for I think.

ChromeView  "This gives your application early access to the newest features in Chromium, and removes the variability due to different WebView implementations in different versions of Android."

https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview

Comment: This will probably work for 4.0 onwards (API 14+), but it won't for 2.3 (as the OP needs), since Chromium uses a lot of APIs not present in 2.3.

Comment: Intel XDK Crosswalk supports an universal webview on all Android 4.x devices. Unfortunately nothing on 2.3 devices

Answer (score 2):

There are not many tools out there, and I doubt that they will be as good as the systemintern WebView.

1. [Chromeview](https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview): **min-API 14**, Chromium-based, seems pretty good and rather bugfree
2. [Geckoview](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2013/10/geckoview-embedding-gecko-in-your-android-application/): **min-API 8**, from Mozilla, likely to have several bugs...
3. <s>[Android-Chromium](https://github.com/davisford/android-chromium)</s>: Removed from github...

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebChrmeClient for this, no need to do any hack and below code will work with HTML as well URl as well as css, Just take a look:

```
public class IjoomerWebviewClient extends Activity {

    private WebView webExternalLinks;
    private IjoomerButton btnClose;
    private String link = "";
    private String IN_CONTENT = "";
    SeekBar seekBar;



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_WEBVIEW_LAYOUT);

 webExternalLinks = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webExternalLinks);
        btnClose = (IjoomerButton) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

getData();
}

  private void getData(){

  getIntentData();

        webExternalLinks.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if(seekBar==null){
                    seekBar = IjoomerUtilities
                            .getLoadingDialog(getString(R.string.dialog_loading_please_wait));
                }
                seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                if(progress==100){
                    seekBar=null;
                }
            }
        });

        webExternalLinks.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webExternalLinks.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webExternalLinks.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webExternalLinks.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webExternalLinks.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        if (link != null && link.length() > 0) {
            if (!link.startsWith("http://") && !link.startsWith("https://")) {
                link = "http://" + link;
            }
            webExternalLinks.loadUrl(link);
        } else if (IN_CONTENT != null && IN_CONTENT.trim().length() > 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // StringBuilder();
            sb.append("<HTML><HEAD><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"weblayout.css\" /></HEAD><body>");
            String str = IN_CONTENT.trim();
            str = str.replaceAll("<iframe width=\"[0-9]*",
                    "<iframe width=\"100\\%");
            str = str.replaceAll("<img[\\w]*",
                    "<img height=\"auto\" style=\"max-width:100\\%\";");
            sb.append(str);
            sb.append("</body></HTML>");
            webExternalLinks.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/css/",
                    sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        }
}



    private void getIntentData() {
        try {
            link = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
            if (link == null) {
                IN_CONTENT = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_CONTENT");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            IN_CONTENT = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("IN_CONTENT");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webExternalLinks.canGoBack()){
            webExternalLinks.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```